# Is it impossible to overload post-increment operator in F#

Tags: f#

I am writing a library for C# developers. The library is written in F#. C# developers would like to use `++` operator on one of the objects. How can I do that ?

I looked up online, found that `++` post-increment operator is a no-such-thing in F#.

Comment: `++` does not make sense in F# due to the immutable nature of variables. Also, it seems an odd requirement of a shared library to want to expose a custom `++` operator. I would be curious to see what your API looks like.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens One of my API is Performance Counters wrapper. And say for counter "Number of Incoming connections" when an incoming connection arrives, it has to be incremented by one.. Let me know if this detail is not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Here is my two cents for what it is worth. I would prefer descriptive methods to magic operators. I would also like to see instance methods instead of static methods (which operators are required to be).

Comment: I know there are two kinds of people. Those who have accepted magic operators and those who are trying to change them to something readable... I am open, not on any side. By the way, I am doing this neat trick on ++ operator definition that does not really create a new object but modify existing one and return the reference of it. Do you see any problem with that ?

Answer (score 8):

Even though F# does not have the `++` operator, you can still define an F# type that supports it:

```
type A(n:int) = 
  member x.N = n
  static member op_Increment (a:A) = A(a.N + 1)
```

The trick is that you have to use the `op_Increment` name for the method, because that's what C# uses for the `++` operator. Unfortunately, F# does not understand the operator and so if you write `member (++) ...`, the compiler will call the method `op_PlusPlus` instead.